# SignalR receive data and show message?

Tags: angular, angular7, toast, toastr

I use `import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";` and use [toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr)

Inside `ngOnInit` I listen data from socket:

```
connection.on("receivePassportData", data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.toastr.error('Title', 'Already checked!');
});
```

So, I see `console.log(data)` each time, it has data, but when I call toast it does not show message.

If call toast using click on DOM element it works fine.

I have AnyDesck access to demonstrate a issue

Full code is:

```
public run() {
   this.toastr.success('aadadasd', 'Already checked!'); // It works immidiatly
}


ngOnInit() {

        let session = sessionStorage.getItem("credentials");
        if (session) {
            let _session = JSON.parse(session);
            this.userId = _session.user.id;
        }

        connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
            .withUrl("http://localhost:8002/dataHub")
            .build();


        //connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000;
        connection
            .start()
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Connected!");
                //let a =  this.toastr;
                    connection
                    .invoke("join", this.userId)
                    .then(() => {
                        // console.log("joined to channel");
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));


            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                return console.error(err.toString());
            });

            connection
                    .on("receivePassportData", data => {
                        //a.error('', 'Checked');
                            this.toastr.error('aadadasd', 'Already checked!');
                        //this.scanDo(data);    

                    });

                connection
                    .on("receiveQRData", data => {
                            this.toastr.error('aadadasd', 'Already checked!');

                    });



        connection.onclose(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

In part of code toaster is not showed:

```
connection.on("receiveQRData", data => {this.toastr.error('aadadasd', 'Already checked!');
});
```

Comment: can you add more code? are there any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors, no warning, okay I will add full code

Comment: I have added ngOnInit with connection and spot where I get data from socket and try to call toaster

Comment: do you get a message on `receiveQRData` message?

Comment: Maybe it is async problem or `this` issue or ngZone

Comment: Yes, I always get message in `receiveQRData` 100%

Comment: what i meant was does the toaster run when you receive a message there?

Comment: also are you injecting the toaster service in the constructor? `constructor(private toastr: ToastrService)`?

Comment: Yes, as you  can see I call toaster immidiatly after console.log, but toaster is not showed, could we move to chat?

Comment: Sure, I have injected

Comment: sure we can if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202918/discussion-between-jason-white-and-jony).

Comment: So, toaster works everywhere bit not in response from socket

Comment: Could socket callback stops life circle Angular?

Comment: are still having issues with this?

Comment: console errors ??

Comment: No errors, and warming

Comment: Yes, Jason I am awaiting you in chat

Comment: hello 2021 just started having this issue in plain vanilla js. anybody got a workaround?